# Highlight 3*3 blocks of diagonal cells with color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Compatibility Metrics sheet and two sheets named Architectural Options.

I take the data from the Architectural Options sheets and write it in the other sheet as shown below.
Compatibility Metrics
[image]

I worked on the code to make the diagonal cells of the sheet, black colored.
However, I would like to make 3*3 cells of the table black colored as shown in the figure, such as: D4:F6, G7:I9 and so on until the last cell of the table.

These cells are dynamic with the data and the size of the diagonal cells varies on the bases of Column B and depending on that I would like to have the diagonal cells highlighted.
I also want to mark all the below cells black from the diagonal cells in the sheet.

```vb
Sub Compatibility_Sheet()

    Dim rowCounter As Double
    Dim maxNoOfOptions As Double
    Dim noOfDecisions As Double
    Dim rowCounterMetrics As Double
    rowCounterMetrics = 4
    Dim columnCounter As Double
    rowCounter = 3
    columnCounter = 2
    Dim morphSheet As String
    morphSheet = "Architectural Options (2)"

    Dim metricsSheet As String
    metricsSheet = "CompatibilityMetrics"

    Dim rng As range
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngEnd As Long
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim colorRange As range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim dia_Range As range

    Sheet1.Activate

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sheet.Name = metricsSheet Then
            Sheet.Delete
        End If
    Next Sheet
  
    If metricsSheet <> "" Then
        'Sheets.Add
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Architectural Options (2)")).Name = "NewSheet"

       ' Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("Sheet1")
        ActiveSheet.Name = metricsSheet
    End If

    'preparing sheet to update
    Sheets(metricsSheet).Activate
    Selection.Merge
    range("B2:B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Requirements"
    range("B2:B3").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 45
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 19.86
    Rows("3:3").RowHeight = 37
    Rows("2:2").RowHeight = 37
    range("B2:B3").Select
    Selection.Font.Size = 14
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Options"
    range("C3").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 45
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
    range("C3").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    
    Do While (Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(2, columnCounter) <> "") ' loop through all columns
        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
    Loop

    maxNoOfOptions = columnCounter - 5

    Do While (Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(rowCounter, 2) <> "") ' loop through all rows
    
        Worksheets(metricsSheet).Cells(rowCounterMetrics, 2) = Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(rowCounter, 3)
        columnCounter = 5
   
        Do While ((Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter) <> ""))
    
            Worksheets(metricsSheet).Cells(rowCounterMetrics, 3) = Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter)

            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            rowCounterMetrics = rowCounterMetrics + 1
        Loop
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Loop

    'Disable popup alerts that appear when merging rows like this
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
     lngStart = 2
     lngEnd = 2

     For myRow = 2 To range("B" & lastRow).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
         If range("B" & (myRow + 1)).Value = "" Then
             'include row below in next merge
             lngEnd = myRow + 1
        Else
            'merge if 2+ rows are included
            If lngEnd - lngStart > 0 Then
                range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Merge
                range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Orientation = 45
                range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Font.Bold = True
                range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
                range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End If

            'reset included rows
            lngStart = myRow + 1
            lngEnd = myRow + 1
        End If
    Next myRow

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set colorRange = range("C4:C60")
    'Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C60")
    
    For Each cell In colorRange
        If cell <> "" Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
            'rng.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = (xlContinuous)
        End If
    Next
    
    With Worksheets(metricsSheet)
        .range("B4:B60").Copy
        .range("D2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        .range("D2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .range("D2").VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .range("C4:C60").Copy
        .range("D3").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    With ActiveSheet

        For r = 4 To 60
            If Cells(r, 3).Value <> "" Then
                Set dia_Range = .range(.Cells(4, 4), .Cells(r, r))
                Cells(r, r).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
                'Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'dia_Range.Select
    End With
    dia_Range.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a very broad "fix my code" question. What troubleshooting have you done? In a specific scenario, you will have an expectation of the desired outcome. If you step through the code, can you identify where the code does things that don't match the expected outcome? THAT is what you need to concentrate on. Once you've isolated the problem, put the problem into words and if you cannot solve that on your own, ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because lastrow is 0, the code gives an error.

If you divide the number by 3 and the remainder is 1, you can get 3*3 cells.

```
For r = 4 To 60
If Cells(r, 3).Value <> "" Then
    k = k + 1
    If k Mod 3 = 1 Then
        Cells(r, r).Resize(3, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 220, 220) '<~~ 3*3 cells
    End If
```

Entire code.

```
Sub Compatibility_Sheet()

    Dim rowCounter As Double
    Dim maxNoOfOptions As Double
    Dim noOfDecisions As Double
    Dim rowCounterMetrics As Double
    rowCounterMetrics = 4
    Dim columnCounter As Double
    rowCounter = 3
    columnCounter = 2
    Dim morphSheet As String
    morphSheet = "Architectural Options (2)"
    
    Dim metricsSheet As String
    metricsSheet = "CompatibilityMetrics"
    
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngEnd As Long
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim colorRange As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim dia_Range As Range
    
    Sheet1.Activate
    
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       If Sheet.Name = metricsSheet Then
          Sheet.Delete
       End If
    Next Sheet
    
    If metricsSheet <> "" Then
        'Sheets.Add
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Architectural Options (2)")).Name = "NewSheet"
    
       ' Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("Sheet1")
        ActiveSheet.Name = metricsSheet
    End If
    
    'preparing sheet to update
     Sheets(metricsSheet).Activate
      Selection.Merge
       Range("B2:B3").Select
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Requirements"
       Range("B2:B3").Select
     With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 45
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 19.86
    Rows("3:3").RowHeight = 37
    Rows("2:2").RowHeight = 37
    Range("B2:B3").Select
    Selection.Font.Size = 14
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Options"
    Range("C3").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 45
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    
    Do While (Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(2, columnCounter) <> "") ' loop through all columns
        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
    Loop
    
    maxNoOfOptions = columnCounter - 5
    
    Do While (Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(rowCounter, 2) <> "") ' loop through all rows
    
    
       Worksheets(metricsSheet).Cells(rowCounterMetrics, 2) = Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(rowCounter, 3)
        columnCounter = 5
    
    Do While ((Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter) <> ""))
    
    
       Worksheets(metricsSheet).Cells(rowCounterMetrics, 3) = Worksheets(morphSheet).Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter)
    
    
        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        rowCounterMetrics = rowCounterMetrics + 1
    Loop
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Loop
    
    
    'Disable popup alerts that appear when merging rows like this
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
     lngStart = 2
     lngEnd = 2
    
     'For myRow = 2 To Range("B" & lastRow).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
     For myRow = 2 To Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row <~~ error: lastrow is 0
        If Range("B" & (myRow + 1)).Value = "" Then
            'include row below in next merge
            lngEnd = myRow + 1
        Else
            'merge if 2+ rows are included
            If lngEnd - lngStart > 0 Then
                Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Merge
                Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Orientation = 45
                Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Font.Bold = True
                Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
                Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End If
    
            'reset included rows
            lngStart = myRow + 1
            lngEnd = myRow + 1
        End If
     Next myRow
    
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     Set colorRange = Range("C4:C60")
     'Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C60")
    
     For Each cell In colorRange
       If cell <> "" Then
     cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
     'rng.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = (xlContinuous)
       End If
    Next
    
    With Worksheets(metricsSheet)
      .Range("B4:B60").Copy
      .Range("D2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
      .Range("D2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
      .Range("D2").VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      .Range("C4:C60").Copy
      .Range("D3").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
    
    
    For r = 4 To 60
    If Cells(r, 3).Value <> "" Then
        k = k + 1
        If k Mod 3 = 1 Then
            Cells(r, r).Resize(3, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 220, 220) '<~~ 3*3 cells
        End If
        Set dia_Range = .Range(.Cells(4, 4), .Cells(r, r))
        
        Cells(r, r).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        
        'Cells(r, r).Select
'        With Cells(r, r).Interior
'            .Pattern = xlSolid
'            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
'            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
'            .TintAndShade = 0
'            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
'            End With
        'Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    'dia_Range.Select
    End With
    dia_Range.Select


End Sub
```