# How can I colour the main diagonal in Excel?

Tags: excel, matrix, colors, conditional-formatting, diagonal

I have an excel table in which a correlation matrix is represented.

I want to paint the main diagonal (A1, B2, C3...) in blue.

The amount of rows is huge, so I cannot just format them manually.

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685258/highlight-33-blocks-of-diagonal-cells-with-color) in which the author shows some code which does this. However, I don't undersstand it. I am a basic excel user, so I don't understand how to implement it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could certainly do it through VBA, and simpler than the thread you mentioned, but solar mike's answer is even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used conditional formatting like so:

On a Mac with Office 365

[image]

On a pc with Office 365:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, I cannot arrive to your screenshot. I am working in windows. I use Home, conditional formatting, new rule, use a formula to determine which line to format. Then I write  =ROW()=COLUMN() in Format values when this formula is true and fill with blue. Could you please be more specific in how to arrive to your solution?

Comment: See the edit, done on a pc and works the same. Check that your formula does not have any " in it.

Comment: And make sure you apply the CF rule to the entire matrix.